# Grey space in listview when adapter is updated

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-arrayadapter

So i have a listview and adapter set up. When i add an item trough adapter.add() in the oncreate() method everything is fine. But when i add it trough a listener it creates this weird grey space as if the items are underneath the other items:

[image]

This is the code that adds the items:

```
                ArrayList<Task> newTasks = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(parser.ParseTasksJson(result)));

                for (int i =0; i < 3;i++)
                {
                    Task task = new Task(i, "Item" + i, 0);
                    tasks.add(task);
                }

                for(Task t : newTasks)
                {

                    adapter.add(new Task(t.getTask_id(), t.getTask_title(), t.getTask_done()));
                }
                adapter.add(new Task(99,"Task after forloop", 0));

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`enter code here`
```

And this is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_home"/>

    <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listview">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: I was not clear enough. The real problem is in the fact that the items  from the parser dont get shown in the listview although they are added to the adapter. SEE updated code.

Comment: do it  android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"

Comment: Is the listener actually being called? Did you check on that?

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen Yes and the items are indeed added to the adapter, there are only not showed in the listview.

Comment: Can I see your adapter item layout as well and the adapter code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working properly, however the problem is in this line:

```
adapter.add(new Task(t.getTask_id(), t.getTask_title(), t.getTask_done()));
```

Make sure that the values are correct, to me it seems that your data does not contain a valid title, and your layout items have a height of `wrap_content`. That being said, the items are added, but not high enough since they don't have any content.

That's why you see that weird grey space, they are actually several items, but not big enough to see.